# What is it called when you use the same first consonant in different words - Example follows

Tags: humor, consonants

I'm going blank here, so forgive me for what should be simple. The search engines weren't helpful. I tried to search.

Example:

`The finicky felines finished their food.`

I'm drawing a serious blank here, so go easy on me.

Comment: To make the question more clear, which consonant are you talking about?

Comment: Edited for posterity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called alliteration.
From Wikipedia:

> Alliteration is a stylistic literary device identified by the repeated
>   sound of the first consonant in a series of multiple words, or the
>   repetition of the same sounds of the same kinds of sounds at the
>   beginning of words or in stressed syllables of a phrase.